# sudo apachectl restart Job for httpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status httpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details

Tags: linux, apache, httpd.conf, centos7

Before my question gets torn apart I have already checked to see if SELinux was disabled and it is and `sudo apachectl restart`  is not working.

I ran into a problem let me start by saying I am a noob, When I ran `sudo apachectl restart` it gave me an error:

```
"Job for httpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status httpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details."
```

when I ran journalctl -xn it states that

```
"no files were found"
```

when I ran `sudo systemctl status httpd.service` I recieved:

```
"httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2015-05-19 07:24:29 SGT; 1min 27s ago   Process: 12590 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)   Process: 12589 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)  Main PID: 12589 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) May 19 07:24:29 synapticenhancements httpd[12589]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 119 of /etc/httpd/conf/h...onf: May 19 07:24:29 synapticenhancements httpd[12589]: DocumentRoot must be a directory May 19 07:24:29 synapticenhancements systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=...LURE May 19 07:24:29 synapticenhancements kill[12590]: kill: cannot find process "" May 19 07:24:29 synapticenhancements systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1 May 19 07:24:29 synapticenhancements systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server. May 19 07:24:29 synapticenhancements systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state. Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

any thoughts?

---

```
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/he/sites"

#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/he/sites">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
#directoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
```

its saying that document root has an error I dont see what the issue is... any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:
apparently I put my file structure in the wrong section so I was essentially referencing something that wasn't there. I moved the file structure to the root directory and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

It's **already** telling you exactly where the error is. You made a change to your config file and either it's invalid or your made a typo. It even tells you what line number it is.

> httpd[12589]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 119 of
>   /etc/httpd/conf/h...onf: May 19 07:24:29 synapticenhancements
>   httpd[12589]: DocumentRoot must be directory May 19 07:24:29

If you edit files using `VIM` you can do `:set number` to see line numbers to find your mistake.